# c++ creating 4 integer from the 16 byte char array

Tags: c++, pointers, integer, binaryfiles

Here is my question

I've read a binary sequence from a binary file into a char array. My binary file is much bigger than my buffer so, I've read it iteratively.

I've read 16 Bytes from the file and store it into `char * myPointer` pointer. Now from myPointer I need to create 4 integer and I dont know how could I do that. Is there anyone to help me ?

Note: I dont have to store it into char array if you have better solution

Comment: What do you mean by _"create"_? What are you going to do with them?

Comment: @Michael does it matter what ı'm gonna do ? Using first 4 bytes of array I want to create the first itneger and goes so on

Comment: You could just read from the source directly to `int` (assuming `std::ifstream file;`): `int i = 0; file.read((void*)&i, sizeof(i));`

Comment: @VioletGiraffe my file is binary file and I need to initialize someties 4 bytes int and sometimes short. Doesnt it problem ? If not, could you write what do you mean ?

Comment: Casting `char*` to `int`: `char * data; int i1 = 0, i2 = 0; i1 = *(int*)data; i2 = *(int*)(data+sizeof(int));` and so on.

Comment: @eday: not a problem. Let me write an answer.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe sorry I did not understand could you be more spesific ? You can try write as an answer

Comment: Is the *real* issue you have that `int` is *not* always 32-bits wide on your target platform(s) ? If so, perhaps `<cstdint>` and `int32_t` may suit this task better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If endianess of stored data is same as endianess of your system, then you can use following code to store read data in `int`:

```
int ints[4];
char bytes[4*sizeof(int)];
memcpy( ints, bytes, sizeof( ints ) );
```

If you have different endianess in input binary file and on your computer, you might want to swap the bits:

```
template< class T>
void changeEndianess( T & input)
{
    char temp[ sizeof( T ) ];
    for( int j=sizeof( T )-1; j>=0; --j )
        temp[sizeof(T)-j-1] = *((char *)&input+j);
    memcpy( &input, temp, sizeof( T ) );
}

// and somewhere in your program:
for( size_t i=0; i<sizeof( ints ); ++i )
{
    changeEndianess<int>( ints[i] );
}
```

To make it use `short` change all `int` in above code to `short`, but it's up to you to decide when it is needed.

Comment: @Lukasz_Daniluk as I said above, I dont always store it into integer, sometimes I need to store it in short also

Comment: This code is just poorly implemented `memcpy`. `memcpy(ints, bytes, sizeof ints);`. Done.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: true, `memcpy` does the same and is shorter.

Comment: I suggest a dedicated function for byte swapping instead of this inner-for... thing...

Comment: To swap endianness `ntoh`[ls] family function may help.

Comment: Provided that he uses `hton`[ls] before storing them in file.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a binary file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>

void main()
{
    std::ifstream file("file.dat", std::ios_base::binary);
    assert(file.is_open());

    int i = 0;
    file.read((void*)&i, sizeof(i));
    short s = 0;
    file.read((void*)&s, sizeof(s));

    ... // And so on
}
```

Obviously, you need to know exactly how to interpret the data, i. e. the file structure (which data type is written where).